# Find maximum and minimum values of three columns in a python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how can I find the difference between maximum and minimum values of three columns in python. (The columns name are POPESTIMATE2010-POPESTIMATE2012)
Then I should find the maximum result among all my records.
in other words, Which county has had the largest absolute change in population within the period 2010-2012?

e.g. If County Population in the 3 year period is 100, 80, 130, then its largest change in the period would be |130-80| = 50.

[image]
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

def answer_one():
    return ((census_df['POPESTIMATE2010'],census_df ['POPESTIMATE2011'],census_df ['POPESTIMATE2012']).max()-(census_df['POPESTIMATE2010'],census_df ['POPESTIMATE2011'],census_df ['POPESTIMATE2012']).min()).max()

answer_one()
```

Comment: Are those the only three columns in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what should be the end result, but if you want to get the column with biggest difference between `max` and `min` value in it, then you can do it like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4,6], 'b':[22,15,6], 'c':[7,18,9]})
>>> df
   a   b   c
0  3  22   7
1  4  15  18
2  6   6   9
>>> diff = df.max() - df.min()
>>> diff
a     3
b    16
c    11
dtype: int64
>>> diff.nlargest(1)
b    16
dtype: int64
```

and if you need just a number then

```
>>> diff.max()
16
```

And if you want to get difference between max and min value in each row, then just do it on different `axis`:

```
>>> diff = df.max(axis=1) - df.min(axis=1)
>>> diff
0    19
1    14
2     3
>>> diff.max()
19
```

Comment: But I believe, using your numbers, saeed would want the result to be 19 (22 - 3), not 16.

Comment: @pshep123 I was editing the answer as you wrote the comment :) The description is not totally clear so I decided to give more options

Comment: What if 22 and 3 were not in the same column?  Would that yield the correct result?

Comment: Thanks for your replying. What dose axis=1 do here? dose it mean the column?

Comment: Axis=1 makes aggreagate to calculate max / min values for each row instead of each colum

Comment: @pshep123 yes if the desired result is the biggest difference between min and max values for each row

Comment: @RomaPekar, right, but I believe he wants the difference between the max and min of basically everything in the dataset.

Comment: Well i'm not sure about this, @saeedtalaee could you clarify?

Comment: @RomanPekar: I need to find max between special columns for each row. I will update my question and show you the data frame.

Comment: @saeedtalaee I think you answer is already there, just depends do you want to find max / min value for every column and then find the biggest difference or do you want to find max / min value for every row and then find the biggest difference

Comment: @RomanPekar: I think your code do the max/min val for all the columns. But I want to do it for 3 columns. In fact I want to know Which county has had the largest absolute change in population within the period 2010-2012?

e.g. If County Population in the 3 year period is 100, 120, 80, 105, 100, 130, then its largest change in the period would be |130-80| = 50.

Comment: @saeedtalaee - so would your function return three numbers in a list or tuple?

Comment: @pshep123: By now yes, but I want the biggest result among my records so, it will return a single value.

Comment: so @saeedtalaee you can have more than one row for each county? Wouldn't you want to calculate county population for each year first?
Anyway I'm not sure I get how you can have six different values of population for 3 year period

Comment: @saeedtalaee I see you edited the answer, so then second approach should be the one

Comment: @RomanPekar: About the first question, Yes I have - About the second question, No I don't want, the final result is important for me. - You are right, I am sorry, I edited the question and decrease the amount of numbers to three.

Comment: Great answer, helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def answer_one():
    max_1 = max(df.max())
    min_1 = min(df.min())
    return max_1 - min_1

print answer_one()
```

and if you want to use a select group of columns:

```
max_1 = max(df[['a','b']].max())
```

Comment: why list? `max( df.max() )` work the same, and same apply to min

Comment: You're absolutely right Copperfield.  Thanks.  Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

max(list) gives you the max element in the list.

min(list) gives you the min element in the list.

The rest I assume should be fairly straightforward to understand!

Comment: I used max and min according to my code, but I couldn't extract it.

Comment: you have to use it like max(list) not list.max()

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean your data first and keep only the columns you need. Then transpose your data frame, and get the difference between max and min from them, and finally from the `diff` series get `idxmax`.

```
import pandas as pd
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
ans_df = census_df[census_df["SUMLEV"] == 50]    
ans_df = ans_df[["STNAME", "CTYNAME", "POPESTIMATE2010", "POPESTIMATE2011", "POPESTIMATE2012"]]
ans_df = ans_df.set_index(["STNAME", "CTYNAME"])
diff = ans_df.T.max() - ans_df.T.min()
diff.idxmax()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as I solved:

```
f1 = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
f1 = f1.ix[:,'POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013'
,'POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']].stack()
f2 = f1.max(level=['STNAME','CTYNAME']) - f1.min(level=['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
return f2.idxmax()[1]
```